# Septic PVC Collar Leaking - Surfacing Wastewater

Tags: leak, septic

#### Issue

I noticed a few days ago that the snow around my septic tank has been melting/iced.  I didn't think much of it at first, because there wasn't much of an odor, and it was clear. However, after showering today, I noticed water pooling about 5ft from exactly where my drain pipe runs from the septic tank toward the field (opened the lid, drew a line and poked the frozen ground and actually hit softness).

Since I had a soft spot to dig, the probability of an issue being directly below was reasonable.  Once I dug to the drain pipe, I immediately noticed water coming through a collar at a joint on the PVC.

#### So I know that I have a leak at this collar, but I have two questions:

1. Is it reasonable for this leak, which is before the distribution box, to have enough pressure to rise to the surface when it's a solid 2-3ft down into the ground?
2. OR, does this probably mean there is a backup more toward the drain field and this was in fact the path of least resistance?

---

#### A few notes

- This is my first winter in this home, but I have never experienced pooling in that area during the summer
- Toilets, sinks, and other plumbing is all normal - no signs of backups or slowing (also, see water level below the drain pipe in image below)
- And because some always assume the worst in people -> **I of course will be calling a professional on Monday and am taking this seriously**

#### Images

Inside the lid - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YdZp.jpg

Showing where that drain pipe goes and how far from it where the surfacing is occurring - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNfAn.jpg

The pipe where the collar leak is (arrow for where I noticed it gushing out at one point while digging) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VgbD.jpg

---

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you have a septic system pumpout and inspection as part of the house purchase process?

Comment: It was probed for how much solid was in the tank, and the company who did the regular maintenance was contacted for recent pump which was 1.5 years ago.  Inspector, who was hired directly through my lender and so I cannot verify his qualifications, said findings were adequate.